Convergence analysis for $x_{k+1}=A\lvert x_k\rvert+c$
I have the following iteration
$$x_{k+1}=A\lvert x_k\rvert+c $$ where $x_k \in \mathbb R^n$ and $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ is a square matrix. The absolute value if taking over the elements. I want to analyze when it converges, which obviously depends on the properties of $A$ and the initial condition $x_0$. $c$ is some constant vector, not necessarily positive. I am looking for references, books or articles on this specific problem. Of course I could look up some nonlinear systems books but I am wondering if there are some works on this specific problem. Thanks In advance.
